# Responsive Images on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a page with an logo on the left, and a *responsive* image on the right (bottom).

Things seem to respond with Safari, but not with Firefox. I looked around and added the following thinking it would help with Firefox, but it doesn't seem to be the case :(

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .mic img {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have the right side image be automatically resized in height, while keeping its ratio. Can anybody tell me what the issue is?

- http://jsfiddle.net/w2ebvkr7/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't *you* tell us what the issue is. What do you expect that code to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the desired result would be? What's supposed to be the behavior of the image? You're not being clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry... my bad, edited the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the -moz-document with normal rule.

Invert the order to obtain the right effect
https://jsfiddle.net/w2ebvkr7/3/

```
.mic img {
    max-height:100%; 
    width:auto !important;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .mic img {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested your jsfiddle update on Firefox, but the right image does not seem to be resizing

Comment: in my Firefox (24) has the same behaviur of Chrome and more or less the same of Safari. In your fiddle (and ofc mine) to see a full resizing you need to resize a lot the quadrant, but it's out  of your question.

Answer (score -1):

Please try using box-sizing: border-box, like:

```html
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .mic img {
        width: 100% !important;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```